# mount Linux NFS. rpc.statd is not running

Tags: linux, nfs

I have Ubuntu 12.04 as the NFS server. The clients are Linux. My  `/etc/exports` file has 1 line,

```
/folderToExport *(rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

`/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server status` shows that the NFS share is working as expected. The problem is that whenever I attempt to mount the NFS share from another Linux host, stdout says

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking
mount.nfs: use '-o nolock'...or start statd
```

`ps -ef |grep statd` shows that `rpc.statd` is already running, so why do they say to "start statd"?

Including their `-o nolock` suggestion allows for the mount NFS to occur, but then the mounted NFS becomes read-only. The `/etc/exports` file asks for `rw`.

How do you start statd? Is the NFS client or server missing some configuration?

---

Here's what worked for me. Make a declaration for each shared folder in `/etc/exports`, e.g.

```
/folderToExport *(rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

`statd` can be started by

`service statd stop` followed by

`service statd start`. Then `ps -ef |grep statd` shows

`statd     1994     1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd -L`

Once you've verified that `statd` is running, next run `mount` from the Linux client,

`mount 192.168.1.3:/folderToExport /mountFolder`

There should no longer be a message `rpc.statd is not running ... start statd`

Finally, be sure that permissions on NFS server allow for `rw` permissions. (Modifying the `/etc/exports` file alone was insufficient)

`chmod 0777 /folderToExport -R`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`statd` is part of the package `nfs-common`. You could probably find that yourself with `locate statd` which gives you among others `/etc/init.d/statd`.

You can start `statd` with:

```
service statd start
```

But it should normally have started on system boot but maybe there is something else going wrong. You should check your log files: `grep statd /var/log/*` to see if there are reasons why that did not start.

Your `/etc/exports` looks ok to me. I use:

```
/data0    *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

on my server and:

```
192.168.0.2:/data0 /data0   nfs  defaults,noauto,user 0 0
```

in the `/etc/fstab` on my client.

Comment: I can't issue the command `sudo service statd start` on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @puk you probably did not install `nfs-common`. If you don't you get `statd: unrecognized service`. After `apt-get install nfs-common` you'll get `start: Job is already running: statd`

Comment: I just checked it again, and it works on 2 Ubuntu computers, but it doesn't work on raspbian even though nfs-common is installed.

Comment: @puk I only checked on Ubuntu 13.10 for Intel on a VM. I am sorry, but I have no access to raspbian and cannot help you there.

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer that worked on Raspbian for me [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10403/nfs-server-not-starting-portmapper-is-not-running).

Enable the rpcbind and nfs services.

`sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable`

`sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable`

Restart the rpcbind service

`sudo service rpcbind restart`

Answer (score 2):

If rpcbind and statd are enabled and running and you still get this error message it is possible that the host is configured with restrictive tcp wrappers.
The following error will be logged:

```
rpc.statd: Failed to read /var/lib/nfs/state: Success
```

In that case you should add the following to /etc/hosts.allow:

```
rpcbind: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Roaima, I hope that I've made it clearer now - please review again.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/default/nfs-common`, insert the `yes` in `NEED_STATD=yes`.

Comment: Such short answers often greatly benefit from expansion to add explanation, or relevant source material.

Comment: This doesn't help either on a raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

start rpcbind and nfslock services.[reference](https://backdrift.org/fixing-rpc-statd-running-required-remote-locking)

```
/etc/init.d/rpcbind start
/etc/init.d/nfslock start
```