# Not mounting NFS shared folders with vagrant libvirt provider in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, nfs, vagrant, libvirt

I have a problem with VM virtualization and vagrant libvirt provider for mounting NFA shared folders.

With the help of @Infernix in github, I was able to properly install the instance of libvirt but the problem now is to mount the shared directory with the VM.

References to installation:

https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/710

Ow, never see error in mount nfs with vagrant before. :o

```
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
Active: active (exited) since Sun 2016-12-18 20:21:10 BRST; 15h ago
=> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.121.1:/home/tosystems/Documents/projects /home/vagrant/vagrant_projects
result=$?
if test $result -eq 0; then
if test -x /sbin/initctl && command -v /sbin/init && /sbin/init 2>/dev/null --version | grep upstart; then
    /sbin/initctl emit --no-wait vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/home/vagrant/vagrant_rojects
fi
else
    exit $result
fi


Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

.

I follow the @HalosGhost hints in link below, but I not succeeded.

[mount Linux NFS. rpc.statd is not running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77055/mount-linux-nfs-rpc-statd-is-not-running)

I changed the synced_folders parameter in Vagrant file and added:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/projects", "/home/vagrant/vagrant_projects", 
type: "nfs", nfs_version: 4, "nfs_udp": false, mount_options: ["rw", "vers=4", "tcp"]
```

but output here yet:

```
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2016-12-18 20:21:10 BRST; 19h ago
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=4,rw,vers=4,tcp 192.168.121.1:/home/tosystems/Documents/projects /home/vagrant/vagrant_projects
result=$?
if test $result -eq 0; then
if test -x /sbin/initctl && command -v /sbin/init && /sbin/init 2>/dev/null --version | grep upstart; then
/sbin/initctl emit --no-wait vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/home/vagrant/vagrant_projects
fi
else
exit $result
fi


Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

it did not work in the end.

. **EDIT:** Uzing `rsync`:

```
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /home/tosystems/ => /vagrant


There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /home/tosystems/
Guest path: /vagrant
Command: "rsync" "--verbose" "--archive" "--delete" "-z" "--copy-links" "--no-owner" "--no-group" "--rsync-path" "sudo rsync" "-e" "ssh -p 22 -o     LogLevel=FATAL  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh.661 -o ControlPersist=10m  -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i '/home/tosystems/.vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/private_key'" "--exclude" ".vagrant/" "/home/tosystems/" "vagrant@192.168.121.229:/vagrant"
Error: symlink has no referent: "/home/tosystems/.config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie"
symlink has no referent: "/home/tosystems/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock"
rsync: write failed on "/vagrant/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-amd64/0/libvirt/box.img": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```